# MVC Passing Model of Tuple Item1 to Partial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that takes in an instance of `getbldgaddr_Result`. I am trying to create a view that uses partials to put two separate viewmodels on the page. Below is the "Parent View"

```
@using DirectoryMVC.Models

@model  Tuple<getbldgaddr_Result,getadministrators_Result>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Central Office";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Central Office</h2>
<div class="row">
    @*Display the getAddress view*@
    @Html.Partial("_BuildingAddress", Model.Item1)

</div>
```

So above I am using Item1 from the model that is a `getbldgaddr_Result`. I have tried casting it to `getbldgaddr_Result` as well, but I get the below error.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Tuple`2[DirectoryMVC.Models.getbldgaddr_Result,DirectoryMVC.Models.getadministrators_Result]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'DirectoryMVC.Models.getbldgaddr_Result'.

The actual controller is...

```
public class BuildingAddressController : Controller
    {
        private DirectoryEntities de;

        public BuildingAddressController()
        {
            de = new DirectoryEntities();
        }
        // GET: BldgAddr
        public ActionResult BldgAddr(getbldgaddr_Result bldgres)
        {
            //getbldgaddr_Result bldgResult  = de.getbldgaddr(district, bldg_no, null).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(bldgres);
        }
    }
```

My guess is, I can have it take a tuple object as the parameter, but this seems counter intuitive. the Building Address, does not need anything in regards to administration.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why send a `Tuple` back to the view? Just create a parent viewmodel having two child viewmodels—i.e. one for each item of the tuple—and return that from the controller instead.

Assuming a `Tuple<Class1, Class2>`, you could structure your viewmodel like this:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public Class1 ChildViewModel1 { get; set; }
    public Class2 ChildViewModel2 { get; set; }
}
```

On the controller side, you'd simply do:

```
var parentViewModel = new ParentViewModel 
                      { 
                          ChildViewModel1 = Tuple.Item1, 
                          ChildViewModel2 = Tuple.Item2 
                      };
return View(parentViewModel);
```

Your view would then be:

```
@model ParentViewModel

// ...
@Html.Partial("_Partial1", Model.ChildViewModel1)
@Html.Partial("_Partial2", Model.ChildViewModel2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Model.Item1 is not null. When the member/property you're passing in is null, MVC reverts back to the parent type.